# Why does RAD jump on Object.wait calls in debug mode?

Tags: websphere, rad

If I start up my WebSphere 7 Portal Sever in "Debug" using the Rapid Application Developer, threads are suspended, RAD asks me to switch to debug mode. Then I can see in the debug view for example the following stack trace:

```
Daemon Thread [wpsDefaultWorkManager.Alarm Pool : 1] (Suspended)    
    Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]  
    Object.wait(long) line: 196 
    <unknown receiving type>(BoundedBuffer).waitGet_(long) line: 187    
    BoundedBuffer.take() line: 549  
    ThreadPool.getTask(boolean) line: 865   
    ThreadPool$Worker.run() line: 1557
```

Or this one:

```
Daemon Thread [WorkManager.PortalSearchIndexWorkManager : 1] (Suspended)    
    <unknown receiving type>(Object).wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]    
    <unknown receiving type>(Object).wait(long) line: 196   
    <unknown receiving type>(BoundedBuffer).waitGet_(long) line: 187    
    <unknown receiving type>(BoundedBuffer).take() line: 549    
    <unknown receiving type>(ThreadPool).getTask(boolean) line: 865 
    <unknown receiving type>(ThreadPool$Worker).run() line: 1557
```

I can then just resume execution and everything seems fine, but why does RAD jump in there as if I had set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Hope there are no breakpoints from your code or breakpoints that you gave when some exception happens.If that is not the case.

Try this 
Might be because there is an uncaught exception and you might have enabled the RAD option to suspend on exception.

In RAD
Go to Windows>Preference>Java>Debug ,uncheck the option "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions"

Try starting the server after that .